# How to `dump` a svn database?

Tags: svn, version-control, visualsvn-server

I have VisualSVN Server installed on my personal laptop, and now that I'm leaving the company I would like to make a dump of all SVN repositories, alongside with history, comments,etc.

I store many personal projects in this localserver and I want to keep the history of each project.

Is it possible?

EDIT: **you all answered my question** - but I can only approve one. thank you all very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re31.html):

svnadmin dump REPOS_PATH [-r LOWER[:UPPER]] [--incremental]

Answer (score 2):

Yep use hotcopy http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re33.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `svnadmin dump`. Here's [some explanation on this](http://daveharris.wordpress.com/2008/08/05/svn-dump-parts-of-a-repository/). Like in:

```
svnadmin dump {path-to-repository} > C:\your-repository.svn-dump
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, assuming you have admin access to the repository.  I've never done this from VisualSVN, but at the command line you would use the command

> svnadmin dump

(The usual disclaimers about making sure you are legally allowed to keep a copy of work you did for a company you are leaving applies.)